# Blender rigid bodies getting stuck in each other

Tags: animation, mesh, physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I am trying to make a pinball simulation with blender and have been constantly having an issue where the pinball (a ragdoll) keeps on getting stuck inside the obstacles:
[image: the stickman's arm is stuck inside another rigid body]
The simulation works by starting the animation and using the controller object to rotate the paddles. The paddles have a driver attached to them where the controller object’s Z changes the rotation of the paddles. The Z of the controller is limited to 0-15.
Video on how to use: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/bg58lgm76uu1bhjqhyi59/pinballguide.mp4?rlkey=im54ws266z3qfa2ohzj9qs0uk&dl=0
File Link: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/5aorzcunqgd28m5930tmd/pinball.blend?rlkey=8cosbs6m3osgkq90f4u2h94g3&dl=0

Comment: one problem for sure is your wrong face orientation of some parts of the body. But even after correcting that, it happened - so i don't know how to solve that.